# Import data from Excel, can look better?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Can you have a look at this part of function and tell me, if that could be better?

I have an Excel file looks like this:

> IMIE | NAZWISKO | ULICA |NRDOMU...
>
> JANE | FOX | XXY | 23...
>
> ANTHONY | WALES | QWER | 555...

And I need to allocate person from this .xlsx file to List.

Enum type before:

> ```
>     enum Headers
>     {
>         IMIE = 0, // column nbumber, first 0 not 1
>         NAZWISKO,
>         ULICA,
>         NRDOMU,
>         NRLOKALU,
>         KODPOCZTOWY,
>         MIASTO,
>     }
> ```

```
string[] array = new string[endPosition.Column];              
for (int row = startPosition.Row + 1; row <= endPosition.Row; ++row)
                    {

                        for (int column = startPosition.Column; column <= endPosition.Column; ++column)
                        {
                            array[column - 1] = currentWorksheet.Cells[row, column].Text;

                        }
                        personList.Add(new Person(array[(byte)Headers.IMIE],
                                                    array[(byte)Headers.NAZWISKO],
                                                    new Addres(array[(byte)Headers.ULICA],
                                                                array[(byte)Headers.NRDOMU],
                                                                array[(byte)Headers.NRLOKALU],
                                                                array[(byte)Headers.KODPOCZTOWY],
                                                                array[(byte)Headers.MIASTO]
                                                                )));
                        Array.Clear(array, 0, endPosition.Column); //reduplication exclude for example number of local
                    }
```

I'm using epplus library.

Comment: Are you getting errors? What is wrong with what you posted? We shouldn't have to look through your code and try to find what's wrong ourselves.

Comment: @DangerZone I'm not getting errors. That thread is rather codereview than finding for bugs.

Comment: There's http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case for generations :) 
I review this code like that and it's more flexible:

```
for (var row = startPosition.Row + 1; row <= endPosition.Row; ++row)
                {
                    _personList.Add(new Person(currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.IMIE].Text,
                                                currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.NAZWISKO].Text,
                                                new Address(currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.ULICA].Text,
                                                            currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.NR_DOMU].Text,
                                                            currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.NR_LOKALU].Text,
                                                            currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.KOD_POCZTOWY].Text,
                                                            currentWorksheet.Cells[row, (int) Headers.MIASTO].Text
                                                            )));
```